# "Invalid List Template" when migrating SharePoint site

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-foundation, error, template

I'm currently in the process of migrating some SharePoint sites to SharePoint Foundation 2013. However, there is one site where I keep getting the error `"Invalid List Template"`
I turned off the custom errors in the web.config, which throws the same error as shown below.
[image: Invalid list template error]

I also noticed that some sites fail to load. For example, when i append the following URL to my site: `/_layouts/settings.aspx` it works. But when i click on a link on this page, some pages work and some don't, with an "`404 not found`" error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who still works on WSS 3.0 (Windows SharePoint Services):

I managed to solve this problem by installing Service Pack 3 on the original source server, since this is a very old SharePoint-site.
When I ran the SharePoint configuration wizard again, the problem went away.

You can then detach/attach the database like you would during a normal upgrade ;)